# Save WordprocessingMLPackage to ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, openxml, docx, docx4j

How can I save a org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage instance into ByteArrayInputStream, then It can be downloaded from server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot save to a `ByteArrayInputStream` ... ever.  A `ByteArrayInputStream` is an `InputStream` and you don't / can't write to an `InputStream`.

However you can write something to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, get the byte array, and create a `ByteArrayInputStream` wrapper for the array.

(I'm assuming that there is a way to save one of those instances to an OutputStream or Writer ...)

---

Well, my assumption was wrong, and `WordprocessingMLPackage`'s only `save` method saves to a `File`.  (I guess someone didn't get the memo on how to design flexible I/O apis ...)

But the source code ( [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/docx4j/docx4j/2.7.1/docx4j-2.7.1-sources.jar!/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/WordprocessingMLPackage.java?format=ok) ) offers some clues on how you could implement it yourself.  The method is as follows:

```
public void save(java.io.File docxFile) throws Docx4JException {

    if (docxFile.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {

        // Create a org.docx4j.wml.Package object
        FlatOpcXmlCreator worker = new FlatOpcXmlCreator(this);
        org.docx4j.xmlPackage.Package pkg = worker.get();

        // Now marshall it
        JAXBContext jc = Context.jcXmlPackage;
        try {
            Marshaller marshaller=jc.createMarshaller();

            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
                                                   Boolean.TRUE);
            NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.setProperty(marshaller, 
                    NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.getPrefixMapper());          

            marshaller.marshal(pkg, new FileOutputStream(docxFile));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Docx4JException("Error saving Flat OPC XML", e);
        }   
        return;
    }

    SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(this); 
    saver.save(docxFile);
}
```

It looks like you should be able to copy this code in a helper class, and tweak it to save to a `OutputStream` rather than (specifically) a `FileOutputStream`.  Note that the `SaveToZipFile` class has alternative `save` methods that write to an `OutputStream`.

Comment: I end up save the generated docx into temporary folder, and convert it to ByteArrayOutputStream, thanks.

Comment: @user200340 How did you do to convert please ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found an easier way to do it without having to change the save() function. Source [here](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/urgent-output-stream-rendering-to-browser-t320.html) and I made a few edits:

For a WordMLPackage p and HttpServletResponse response:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
String fileName = "MyDocument.docx";
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${fileName}");
SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(p);
saver.save( response.getOutputStream() );
```

import statement:

```
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.*
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 3.1.0 version you can use `save(OutputStream outStream)`:

```
/**
     *  Save this pkg to an OutputStream in the usual zipped up format
     *  (Docx4J.FLAG_SAVE_ZIP_FILE)
     *  
     *  @since 3.1.0
     */ 
    public void save(OutputStream outStream) throws Docx4JException {
        save(outStream, Docx4J.FLAG_SAVE_ZIP_FILE);                     
    }
```