# Getting InputStream of a .docx file using docx4j

Tags: java, ftp, docx4j

I have an application which saves .docx files to a FTP server. To store the file on the FTP server the FTP client needs the InputStream of the file, but here comes the problems. I use docx4j to save the text I want to a temp file on the file system, after that I get the InputStream of that file and stores it on the FTP server. But when I try to open it says that it is corrupted. Here is my sample code:

```
 public void setText(String text) throws BusinessException {
    //My utility class, used for ftp processes(such as storing, deleting files
    FtpProcesses ftp = new FtpProcesses(Consts.ADMIN_FTP_USERNAME, UserType.ADMIN); 
    String filePath = ftp.getFileFolderRelativePath(FileType.ARTICLE, String.valueOf(this.getVersionsCount()), String.valueOf(this.getId()));
    File outputFile;
    InputStream stream;
    Text fileText;
    R run;
    P paragraph;
    ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
    try {
        outputFile = File.createTempFile("tempFile", ".docx");
        paragraph = factory.createP();
        run = factory.createR();
        fileText = factory.createText();
        fileText.setValue(text);
        run.getContent().add(fileText);
        paragraph.getContent().add(run);
        WordprocessingMLPackage word = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
        word.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(paragraph);
        word.save(outputFile);
        stream = new FileInputStream(outputFile);
        ftp.uploadFile(filePath, stream);
    } catch (IOException | Docx4JException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new BusinessException(Errors.FILE_UPLOAD_ERROR);
    }
}
```

So as you can see I getting the InputStream directly after saving the file. Is there some other way for getting it with docx4j so that it can be saved properly on the ftp?

Comment: What mode do you use in ftp upload?

Comment: I am using STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE.

Comment: Did you try to save as is stated in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360867/save-wordprocessingmlpackage-to-bytearrayinputstream ?

Comment: @MariusŽilėnas thanks for asking about the mode. I was using the wrong mode- the correct one is BINARY_FILE_TYPE. Now everything is and it is working.

Comment: glad to help with it and hear that it is working:).